# Unable to register app in /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx

Tags: provider-hosted-app

I receive an error when after clicking the `Create` button in sitename /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx. Browsing the log files I see

> Error when create app 9071df94-8af7-4a53-8bac-44abad787b67,
>   Exception=System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access
>   is denied.
>
> Application error when access /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx,
>   Error=Access is denied.

Comment: What environment you are using? SharePoint Online? Or SharePoint on premise?

Comment: It is on premise

Comment: Can you share your full url format where you are trying to register?